# Load Email Client from Google sheet

Tags: google-sheets

I am looking for the ability to load a list of items and allow the user to click the link which will open their email client or send create a method where it tells us the user wants more information in this row of data.  So the user would email us.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to add a [**hyperlink**](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093313) and use the `mailto:` protocol.

The format of hyperlink is:

```
HYPERLINK(url, [link_label])
```

So, you might have something in a cell like:

```
=HYPERLINK("mailto:sales@example.com?subject=Inquiry about part number " & A7, "Contact us for a quote")
```

Assuming the user's mail client is set up correctly, this should open a compose window with an email message addresses to "sales@example.com" and a subject of "Inquiry about part number {whatever value is in cell A7}".

Comment: I get a blank URL when i put that in.  It works on the Mobile but not on laptop.  here is an edible version of it.  https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1FSPLIvwfQP7KHMYq-EaXfv49ESyOMX_S1eqzI0-pBj0/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Then you're not set up to handle `mailto:` protocol on your desktop.